# Display "(Cell C4) Cell A2" if Cell C4 contains "HOT" or "WARM"

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Here's what I currently have, I'm working on a small sales pipeline:
[image]

I need it to look like this in another sheet:
[image]

I'm using this code:

```
=IF(OR('Sponsorship '!C4="HOT",'Sponsorship '!B4="WARM"),'Sponsorship '!A4,"")
```

I was going to attempt how to get the prefix `WARM` or `HOT` appended at a later time, but I'm already facing issues as I can't figure out how to get cells that do not meet either criteria (WARM/HOT) to just move on to the next row, rather than show blank. See image of what i mean:

[image]

Your response would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* I'm not clear on where the data is *coming from* in the first place, but this seems like it would be easiest on a *single* worksheet (as opposed to duplicating the same data on another worksheet). Combine Status+Name in the original table (in an additional column, and hiding the Status &Name columns, if necessary), and then use **AutoFilter** to display only desired rows/when required. Check out the [tour] (earn your first badge!) and "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve], also this [checklist](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/stack-overflow-question-checklist/) from [so]'s top user.

Comment: Thank you for the response :). I have specific reasons for requiring this to be done in a separate sheet.. I've gotten around it by using a combination of pivot tables and simple vlookups. Thank you for the warm welcome!